# How to use upper_bound on array of pair<int,int> in C++?

Tags: arrays, c++11, std-pair, upperbound

I want to use upper_bound on array of pair and that too using a comparator function that compares the second parameter of pair. Please help.

**Code**:

```
bool cmp(const pair<int,int> &p1, const pair<int,int> &p2)
{
    return p1.second<p2.second;
}

int subsets(pair<int,int> time[], int p)
{
    if(p == 0)  return 1;
    int j = upper_bound(time, time+p, time[p], cmp) - time;
}
```

**EDIT**: I have corrected the return type but I don't seem to get what I wanted as an output.
I have an array of `pair<int,int>` named time which contains the start and end time as the first and second parameter respectively and sorted according to end time in increasing fashion.

Presently I am at index p. I want to find the maximum index of the array( = j), such that `time[j].second <= time[p].first`.
**Eg.**
time = { (1,5), (4,7) , (6, 12) } and if p = 2(0 based indexing) then j should be = 0 (as 5 <= 6 but 7 > 6) but upper_bound gives me j = 2.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does the job :)

```
bool compareit(int n, pair<int,int> &p)
{
    return p.second > n;
}

int subsets(pair<int,int> time[], int p)
{
    if(p == 0)  return 1;
    int j = upper_bound(time, time+p, time[p].first, compareit) - time;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your `cmp` function, the error was raised when you try to store the return value of `std::upper_bound` into `int j`.

According to the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), `std::upper_bound`:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is greater than value, or last if no such element is found.

So to obtain the position of the found element in your `time` array, you need to modify your code as follows:

```
int j = upper_bound(time, time + p, time[p], cmp) - time;
```

or equivalently, use the `std::distance` function.

Also, don't forget to check whether such element exists (i.e. whether `std::upper_bound` returned `time + p` in this case).